# C++ scraping web

Tags: c++, web-scraping

I have for some time now tried to figure a way to do some simple scraping of websites in C++.
I have stumbled across the cURL library but I am unable to install it properly, so I'll try another approach.

Does any of you know of any method? Using cURL is an acceptable answer if followed by a thorough explanation of how to install it on Win32 using C++.

Can I do it somehow easier or is it an impossible task in C++? If so, will it be easier to venture into using C#, although I have never used that before either?

Comment: If you don't explain exactly what problems you're having with cURL, no-one can help you fix them. As for what language is best, that's entirely subjective.

Comment: It's possible in C++, because C++ is general-purpose turing-complete language.

Comment: @hate-engine: Network support is not required for turing-completeness :)

Comment: @Philipp, sure, but for been "general-purpose"? ;)

Answer (score 5):

As Vlad Lazarenko posted as a comment, [the official install guide for cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) can help you to install it.

When you still can't get it to work, you can always implement HTTP yourself. It's not a very complicated protocol. You just create a socket using Winsock, connect to the webserver on port 80, and send these strings:

```
"GET /example.html HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"Host: www.example.com\r\n"
"\r\n"
```

and the webserver will answer with its own HTTP header, followed by the content of example.html (or an error message).

Regarding your question about C#: When I would have to choose between implementing a web scraper in C++ or C#, I would choose the latter, because it comes with HTTP support and much superior string handling features out-of-the-box without requiring any libraries. But that's under the assumption that 1. me and my team know both languages equally well and 2. there are no requirements I don't know about which would rather point to C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing web scraping, C++ is probably not the best language to use. C++ is a low-level language which makes it great for performance but for tasks like this it would just take unnecessarily long to end up with a solution. Have a look at Python and the `urllib2` library, or other scripting languages like Perl or Ruby.

Comment: +1 for python and urllib2. it takes only a few lines to work just fine.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a suggestion of another technique entirely. Web Scraping *can* be done in C++ even if it is a bad idea, and I came here hoping to see on post on how.